# Silverlight functionality not working on Mac

Tags: c#, macos, silverlight-5.0

I have an application built in silverlight and it has a functionality that uploads an excel file and an image file on individual button clicks.
When I open the app on windows (Internet Explorer, Safari, Chrome) - it works smoothly.

When I open the same application on Mac, this functionality (image and excel upload) fails.

1. Button_1 to Upload Image - I do get the file dialog box, I select the file, but when I say Ok, I do not get any errors, but the image upload does not work (I do not see the image uploaded)
2. Button_2 to Upload Excel -  I do get the file dialog box, I select the file but when I say Ok (Error message: `Excel is already open` but I have checked numerous times... Excel is closed)

This error I am getting is only on Mac Machines... On all windows machines, it works smoothly

Silverlight Version - 5.1.302, Mac - 10.7.5, Browser - Safari - 6.1.1

Any clues?

Comment: You can only contact Microsoft support http://support.microsoft.com.

Comment: Please can you post a sample of the code being executed in both cases? This will enable people to respond to your question more promptly, and avoid getting the question closed as `off topic: not programming related`

Comment: @LexLi, Chris                                                    Made some changes in browser settings and things working fine... mentioned those steps in response below.  Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution for this. We need to make some security changes in the Safari settings. Following are the steps I tried and things working fine.  1.  Open Safari
2.  Open desired application where you have issue
3.  Click Safari from Top Menu Go to Preferences  Security  Internet Plug-ins ( Click on Manage Website Settings ) 
4.  Left Window locate Silverlight and select it.
5.  After selecting Silverlight  On right side window  You will see “website you have opened” and a dropdown  From Dropdown  Select   Allow Always and Run in Unsafe Mode
6.  You will be prompted with some warning message – so that is ok… Say Ok and then click Done.

1. Close Safari completely – Make sure Safari browser is closed completely.
2. Open New Safari browser instance and launch application.  Since I am running application in secure network - running application in unsafe mode do not cause any security level issues.